# How to deploy spring boot application on multiple machines?

Tags: java, spring-boot

We have a spring boot app that contains a module functionality which will be used by several other consumers, presently it is deployed on only one machine(EC2 instance), can someone tell me how to deploy the same app in multiple machines and therafter how to manage all such instances? 
Thanks

Comment: Use a load balancer and attached multiple instances which run the same app to it.

Comment: can you give me a link to how to do it? sorry, but i am new to this.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/deploying-a-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: Hey, apparently beanstalk is ruled out as it is costly, any other options?